# Split and rename java created xml file

Tags: java, xml, shell

I'm creating an xml-file in java using jaxb and XmlStreamWriter. This will become a very large file and has to be split into several pieces of max. 200MB. These pieces shouldn't be readable xml anymore.

The name of this file is very specific using the date and several parameters and at the end they're numbered like this: '3.1', '3.2', '3.3' where the first number is the number of chunks created and the second number is the following-number of the file. The first part of the filename (apart from the numbering) is created in the java application.

Now I want to create a UNIX script that calls the java application with the needed parameters, splits the file and renames the chunks.

I know the commands to call the java application and to split and rename files but I don't know how to combine them because I only now the filename in the Java application so I can't decide which file has to be split and renamed.

Does anyone have an idea how to deal with it?

EDIT:
Ok I'll try to be a bit less vague.

The application I created creates very large xml-files. The name of this files are in the following format: FI.DB2P.107601.20130130.20010.T.1.1 . This name contains some identification numbers and the date when the file is created. The first part of the name is created in the Java application like this: FI.DB2P.107601.20130130.20010.T.

Now this file should be split into several chunks of max. 200 MB each. Then the created chunks should have the same name as the 'base-file' but they have to end with 'T.3.1', 'T.3.2' and 'T.3.3' for example.

My question now is how I can obtain the filename of the file created by the java application in the Unix script. The filename is pretty complex and contains data from the database so I can't define the name in the Unix script.

I hope it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: your problem is vague, please ask a precise question here. We can't solve your problem with so few details

Answer (score 0):

Is it not the case that your Java process will call the Unix script and therefore will be able to pass it the filename on the command line.

The Unix script can take the filename and run something like `split` on it and then fix-up the filenames to those that your Java process is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand your question that should be fairly easy to do.
When you create your `XMLStreamWriter` you know (hopefully) the name of the file:

```
String fileName = "FI.DB2P.107601.20130130.20010.T.1.1";
XMLStreamWriter writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileWriter(fileName ));
```

Then it's not a problem to pass this name as a parameter to your shell script:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("yourscript.sh " + fileName);
```

`yourscript.sh` will have code to split the file and add incrementing variable to the file name, something like this might work:

```
#!/bin/bash
split -b 200m -a 5 "$1" splited_file

i=1
for file in splited_file*
do
 mv $file $1_${i}
 i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

ps: this script is not thread safe :)